# Why am I receiving this exception in thread main error?

Tags: java

I'm trying to create a program that outputs a user inputted number in words. I'm not 100% sure if this code does exactly what I want it to do yet, but I'm currently having issues with compiling my code. I'm receiving the following error messages:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
    at java.base/java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:937)
    at java.base/java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1594)
    at java.base/java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2258)
    at java.base/java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2212)
    at SayingNumbers.main(SayingNumbers.java:125)
```

and this is the code I'm trying to compile! If you spot any other errors, feel free to point them out!! (I'm sorry it's so long, I'm not really sure where the error is coming from since I'm new to Java!)

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class SayingNumbers {
    public static String oneDigitToStr(int num) {
        switch (num) {
            case 0 : return "zero";
                case 1 : return "one";
                case 2 : return "two";
                case 3 : return "three";
                case 4 : return "four";
                case 5 : return "five";
                case 6 : return "six";
                case 7 : return "seven";
                case 8 : return "eight";
                case 9 : return "nine";
        }
        return"";
    }
    public static String twoDigitToStr(int num) {
            switch(num){
                case 10 : return "ten";
                case 11 : return "eleven";
                case 12 : return "tweleve";
                case 13 : return "thirteen";
                case 14 : return "fourteen";
                case 15 : return "fifteen";
                case 16 : return "sixteen";
                case 17 : return "seventeen";
                case 18 : return "eighteen";
                case 19 : return "nineteen";
            }
            String tens[] = {"twenty", "thirty", "forty", "fifty", "sixty", "seventy", "eighty", "ninety"};
      
            int onesPlace;
            int tensPlace;
            int i;
            i = num;
            onesPlace = i%10; //finding ones place
            i /= 10;
            tensPlace = i; //finding tens place
      
            if(tensPlace == 0) {
                return oneDigitToStr(onesPlace); //for signle digit
            }
            if(onesPlace == 0) {
                return tens[tensPlace - 2]; //for multiples of 10
            }
      
        //for 2 digit numbers which are not multiples of 10
            return tens[tensPlace - 2] + " " + oneDigitToStr(onesPlace);
    }
    public static String threeDigitToStr (int num) {
        String hundreds = "hundred";
        int hundredsPlace;
        int tensPlace;
        int onesPlace;
        int i;
        i = num;
        onesPlace = i % 100;
        hundredsPlace = i / 100;
        i = num;
        i = i - hundredsPlace;
        tensPlace = i / 10;
        if (hundredsPlace == 0) {
            return twoDigitToStr(tensPlace);
        }
        i = num - hundredsPlace;
        return oneDigitToStr(hundredsPlace) + " hundred " + twoDigitToStr(i);
    }
    public static String numToStr (int num) {
        String userNum = Integer.toString(num);
        int billions;
        int millions;
        int thousands;
        int hundredsPlace;
        int tensPlace;
        int onesPlace;
        int i = num;
        int n = userNum.length();
        if (n > 9) {
            if (n < 12) {
                n = 12 - n;
                while (n > 0) {
                    userNum = "0" + userNum;
                    n--;
                }
            }
            billions = Integer.parseInt(userNum.substring(0,3));
            millions = Integer.parseInt(userNum.substring(3,6));
            thousands = Integer.parseInt(userNum.substring(6,9));
            hundredsPlace = Integer.parseInt(userNum.substring(9,12));
            return threeDigitToStr(billions) + " billion " + threeDigitToStr(millions) + " million " + threeDigitToStr(thousands) + " thousand " + threeDigitToStr(hundredsPlace);
        }
        else if (n > 6 && n <= 9) {
            if (n < 9) {
                n = 9 - n;
                while (n > 0) {
                    userNum = "0" + userNum;
                    n--;
                }
            }
            millions = Integer.parseInt(userNum.substring(0,3));
            thousands = Integer.parseInt(userNum.substring(3,6));
            hundredsPlace = Integer.parseInt(userNum.substring(6,9));
            return threeDigitToStr(millions) + " million " + threeDigitToStr(thousands) + " thousand " + threeDigitToStr(hundredsPlace);
        }
        else if (n <= 6) {
            if (n < 6) {
                n = 6 - n;
                while (n > 0) {
                    userNum = "0" + userNum;
                    n--;
                } 
            }
            thousands = Integer.parseInt(userNum.substring(0,3));
            hundredsPlace = Integer.parseInt(userNum.substring(3,6));
            return threeDigitToStr(thousands) + " thousand " + threeDigitToStr(hundredsPlace);
        }
        return "";
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);
        int numEntered;
        while(true) {
        System.out.print("Enter an integer to pronounce (any negative value to exit): ");
        numEntered = scnr.nextInt();
        if (numEntered < 0) {
            break;
        }
        System.out.println(numEntered);
        System.out.println(numToStr(numEntered));
    }
    System.out.println("kthxbye!");
}
}
```

Comment: Your code runs fine on my sys.
The logic's wrong btw.

Comment: @Vishal what are you seeing thats wrong?? I literally can NOT get it to run for some reason

Comment: Are you closing the scanner somewhere in your code? Something like this `scanner.close()`

Comment: I'm not! Also, I'm running it on Terminal in Mac, not sure what you're running it on!

Comment: Just figured out how to make that error message stop! Now I'm having issues with output haha

Comment: What's the issue?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218001/discussion-between-jenna-crist-and-vishal).